# Javascript Output HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if someone could help me with this simple code I am trying to make a banner appear at the top of a webpage for cookies policy (click to agree etc) I have coded the PHP part fine and it makes and detects if cookie policy is agreed however I am having problems using a JS snippet to load the banner to the top of my page.

This is what I am using to display the box and for the example about the code works fine displaying a hyperlink or text (as below) but if I try and add any other type of HTML for example a simple table like this it wont work.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Table </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry updated works with hyperlink

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText()
{
     document.getElementById("new_coder").innerHTML = '<a href="#">sdsd</a>';
}
</script>
<b id='new_coder'>Good Bye World</b>
<input type='button'  value='Change Text'/>
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText()
{
     document.getElementById("new_coder").innerHTML = '<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Table </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
}
</script>
<b id='new_coder'>Good Bye World</b>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a better function for loading HTML snippets into a page via JavaScript. Sorry I am little sketchy on this area.

Thanks Debs

Comment: Please show the code that *doesn't* work instead of the one that works.

Comment: It looks like your `<table>` is outside of your `<body>`. Also, there is no element with an id of changearea

Comment: In terms of offering simple live demos of HTML/CSS/JavaScript (with libraries as required): [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) and [codepen](http://codepen.io/) (among others). For server-side types there's [codepad](http://codepad.org/).

Comment: You can't have line breaks inside a string. Remove them and write the HTML in one row (`'<table><tr><td>...'`)

Answer (score 3):

You have actually encountered a javaScript quirk.

JS has automatic semicolon insertion and what it does is insert on line feed.

if you write your function like this:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xV5PM/)

```
function changeText()
{
     document.getElementById("new_coder").innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>Test</td><td>Table </td></tr></table>";
}
```

It will work.

**notice no line break in code**

You can get a clue by pressing F12 and looking at your console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Just around where you had your line break.

Comment: thank you so much I knew it was something little like that works perfectly now. Also thanks to all the other posters.

Comment: @deb - if you found this answer helpful, the best way to say "thank you" on [so] is by voting or [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). With this, you can write something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#changearea').html('<a href="#">Hyperlink</a>');
});
```

It is more terse and should work across all browsers.

Comment: thanks I was using jquery before an example I found on here the only reason is it is rendering 85kb on load and I wanted a more streamlined script. As GTmetrix shows I got to much JS on page.

Comment: The parameter to `.html()` is the same that `.innerHTML` accepts. If `.innerHTML` doesn't work, neither does `.html()`.

Comment: @Juhana: judging from the source, it does some other trickery that I'm really happy that I don't have to understand. I believe that is the whole point of using an abstraction library that irons out the differences between different browsers, but you have piqued my interest. Can you explain what ``typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) &&
    ( jQuery.support.htmlSerialize || !rnoshimcache.test( value )  ) &&
    ( jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value ) ) &&
    !wrapMap[ ( rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""] )[1].toLowerCase() ]`` is all about?

Comment: @Debra: yes - jQuery takes up approximately 85kb, but many sites are using it anyway. If you use a common CDN, it is likely to be cached in the browser by another page when the user visits yours.

Comment: I'm not saying the *method* is the same, I'm saying the *parameter* is the same. The OP says that `innerHTML` works with hyperlinks but not with tables. If that is the case, the problem is with how she writes the string (as can be seen in the edited question). Using jQuery won't solve the problem --- the string is invalid in either case.

Comment: Sorry about misreading your comment. I just have the opinion that starting to work with client side JavaScript *requires* a use of a library like jQuery, just like very few starts out writing assembly before higher level stuff. The question has the phrase "is there a better way of loading HTML snippets on to a web page", which triggered my jQuery response :)